# Passport js deserialization blacklisted error

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using Nodejs with passport.js. As soon as I run my server on `localhost:3000`, I kept on getting

> Error: failed to deserialize user out of session

I found the solution to this on [this](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/6) Github thread.

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
  done(null, false);  // invalidates the existing login session.
});
```

From the thread:

> As things stand now, as soon as you get a deserialization error
>   you're essentially blacklisted

This might be my poor understanding of sessions but I kept getting the error above even when I restarted the server. Where am I getting blacklisted? Shouldn't restarting the server erase all server sessions?

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  // this user is from your passport strategy
  // for example: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local#user-content-configure-strategy
  // the data you give will store into session
  done(null, user._id); 
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  // the id is from session which store by serializeUser function
  // this function should varify user and return its data to passport
  // when passport jobs done
  // you can access user data from req.user in express; ctx.state.user in koa
  1User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user); // if user is null, will block user
  });
});
```